# SQL Database Publishing wizard with SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, export, publishing, wizard

I'm desperately looking for SQL Database Publishing wizard. I've download it but it seems to require SQL Server 2005. According to http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx it comes with Visual Studio 2008, but my Visual Studio 2008 Professional doesn't have that menu item.

Any ideas how can I get the SQL Database Publishing wizard working with SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 16):

I found the solution online. Here is the steps to solve the issue in case any one else having the same problem. Thanks.

1. Open Control Panel and go to Add or Remove Programs.
2. Right-click the component 'Microsoft Sql Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.3' (or 'Microsoft Sql Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.2' if this older version was installed due to (b) above), and then click Uninstall. Wait for uninstallation to finish.
3. Run SqlPubWizInstaller.exe from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=119368  to re-install 'Microsoft Sql Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.3'. You can verify that it was installed by looking in Add or Remove Programs.

Comment: I have found `Microsoft Sql Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.4` already installed as part of Sql 2005. It workes with Sql2008 and can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4\SqlPubWiz.exe`. Saman, `nice answer` (10 votes). :)

Answer (score 8):

Even this thread is old and created long back... just want to share the solution which I think may be helpful to someone...

Open SSMS(Management Studio) and right click on the database.  Select Tasks--> Generate Scripts.  Select the "Script entire database and all database objects" radiobutton and click Next.

In the "Scripting Options" screen, click the "Advanced" button and in General, change "Types Of Data to Script" to "Schema and Data".

This will generate whole script with data and schema.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Database Publishing wizard is in Visual Studio 2008:

> - **Step 1:** Create a new website by selecting menu File ->New Web Site.
>     Switch to Server Explorer and add a
>     new Data connection and connect to a
>     database. In this case we will use the
>     Northwind database that comes with SQL
>     Express. You should point to the
>     database you want to publish.
> - **Step 2:** Select Northwind.dbo node in Server explorer and right
>     click to bring up the context menu. In
>     the Context menu you have a “Publish
>     to provider…” option.

[Ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx).

> You should be able point to a database
>   on your local machine, and then
>   automatically create a .SQL script
>   file that contains the setup logic
>   needed to re-create a replica of the
>   database on any remote system – for
>   example an external hosting system.
>   This .SQL script includes everything
>   needed to create the database schema
>   (tables, views, sprocs, triggers,
>   full-text catalogs, roles, rules,
>   etc). You also have the option of
>   populating the new database with the
>   same data contents as your local
>   tables.
>
> Most hosters today support the upload
>   and running of .SQL files to their
>   hosted environments using their admin
>   control panels. So, all you need to do
>   is upload and run the .SQL script
>   generated by the Database Publishing
>   Wizard, and you will have a working
>   database in your hosted environment.

Comment: Oh, you need a website project? It doesn't work in other types of projects?

Comment: The publishing wizard addresses the issue where a developer needs to deploy a local database from his development machine to a hosting environment on a remote machine.

Comment: You could craete a temp web site project and then script out your Database.

Answer (score 0):

Install "SQL Server Express Edition With Tools" , then install publishing wizard.